# Existe un equivalente a lastInsertId() para un UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy usando PHP y MySQL con PDO; me gustaría si existe un equivalente al método lastInsertId() que devuelve el último ID de una fila que se ha insertado, pero que me devuelve el último ID de una fila que se actualizó.

Comment: ¿Puedo preguntar qué intentas hacer? Si estás haciendo un UPDATE seguramente estés usando el ID para identificar qué fila se actualizará, si usas otros campos corres el riesgo de que sea más de una fila modificada y por lo tanto no tenga sentido tener lastInsertId (o lastUpdatedId si es que existe)

Comment: Hola Alvaro, se está actualizando todos los hijos de un determinado padre. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En MySQL no existe ninguna función nativa que devuelva el ID (o IDs) de la última fila (o filas) modificada con un `UPDATE` en la base de datos.

En la versión en inglés de StackOverflow [Pomyk y aefxx sugieren una solución interesante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751282/3695983) que funciona tanto para el último ID como grupo de IDs (si más de una fila fue modificada):

```
SET @id_actualizado := 0;

UPDATE nombre_tabla 
SET    nombre_columna = 'valor', 
       id = (SELECT @id_actualizado := id)
WHERE  otra_columna = 'lo_que_sea' 
LIMIT 1; 

SELECT @id_actualizado;
```

Ese código devolverá el ID de la fila actualizada. Ahora, si lo que quieres es devolver todos los IDs de todas las filas modificadas (en caso de ser más de una) separados por comas, entonces sería algo como esto (`id` sería la clave primaria/ID de la tabla):

```
SET @uids := null;

UPDATE nombre_tabla
SET    nombre_columna = 'valor'
WHERE  otra_columna > 5 AND
       ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', id, @uids) );

SELECT @uids;
```

Comment: Es correcto, muchas gracias. @Alvaro

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esto

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection  
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   //ultimo id
   $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
   echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta. @Pit usa PDO y quiere trabajar con un UPDATE; esta respuesta usa MySQLi con un INSERT

Comment: Es correcto @Alvaro, no responde. Ya voy a revisar la tuya. :)